Java 6 on MacOs Sonoma 14.5
I tried on my Sonoma 14.5 to install java6 with homebrew, but it doesn't work with :
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions (apparently it was deprecated)
brew install java6 (No available formula with the name "java6")
Does someone has an idea ? Thanks :)
Here is what I did :
I've put brew tap homebrew/cask-versions and I had this answer :
Error: homebrew/cask-versions was deprecated. This tap is now empty and all its contents were either deleted or migrated.
And When I've put brew install java6 I had this :
Warning: No available formula with the name "java6". Did you mean javacc? ==> Searching for similarly named formulae and casks... ==> Formulae javacc ✔
To install javacc ✔, run: brew install javacc ✔
==> Casks ava ✔
To install ava ✔, run: brew install --cask ava ✔

I was using an app which worked on Catalina with Java 6.
Now you can find the failure report when i'm trying to install my app on Sonoma :
Process: PNS_MAC_6.0 [10766] Path: /Volumes/VOLUME/PNS_MAC_6.0.app/Contents/MacOS/PNS_MAC_6.0 Identifier: PNS_MAC_6.0 Version: InstallAnywhere 2011 Installer (12.5) Code Type: X86-64 (Translated) Parent Process: launchd [1] User ID: 501
Date/Time: 2024-07-30 23:43:09.3265 +0200 OS Version: macOS 14.5 (23F79) Report Version: 12 Anonymous UUID: 189B3180-0A80-D6B1-6361-BB87CEA3ABE4
Sleep/Wake UUID: 7F9035E1-DAB6-4BF2-A670-E80AC5F9FE14
Time Awake Since Boot: 21000 seconds Time Since Wake: 30 seconds
System Integrity Protection: enabled
Notes: PC register does not match crashing frame (0x0 vs 0x100017A78)
Crashed Thread: 0
Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: Namespace DYLD, Code 1 Library missing Library not loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaApplicationLauncher.framework/Versions/A/JavaApplicationLauncher Referenced from: <4FF3E2B1-8C08-F8CF-7092-00A087321243> /Volumes/VOLUME/PNS_MAC_6.0.app/Contents/MacOS/PNS_MAC_6.0 Reason: tried: '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaApplicationLauncher.framework/Versions/A/JavaApplicationLauncher' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaApplicationLauncher.framework/Versions/A/JavaApplicationLauncher' (no such file), '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaApplicationLauncher.framework/Versions/A/JavaApplicationLauncher' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/Library/Frameworks/JavaApplicationLauncher.framework/Versions/A/JavaApplicationLauncher' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaApplicationLauncher.framework/Versions/A/JavaApplicationLauncher' (no such file, not in dyld cache) (terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)
Error Formulating Crash Report: PC register does not match crashing frame (0x0 vs 0x100017A78)
Thread 0 Crashed: 0 Rosetta Runtime Routines 0x100017a78 ??? 1 0x10009a3dc ??? 2 dyld 0x20010ebb7 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 82 3 dyld 0x20010ebe9 abort_with_payload + 9 4 dyld 0x20009b2e5 dyld4::halt(char const*, dyld4::StructuredError const*) + 335 5 dyld 0x2000984e2 dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*) + 4099 6 dyld 0x2000972ff start + 1839
Thread 1:: com.apple.rosetta.exceptionserver 0 runtime 0x7ff7ffd30494 0x7ff7ffd2c000 + 17556
Etc

Time for an upgrade!

Any reason why you require such an ancient java version?

You can always give it a try and build from the sources ;) - https://github.com/openjdk/jdk6

By the way, SDKMAN!

This looks to be an XY Problem. You should provide more clarity why do you need Java 6 specifically.

Until Java 6 Apple built their own version of Java which is not compatible with current versions of macOS. Either use a current version of the JDK or find a supported version of macOS (which was called Mac OS X at the time).

Mac OS X and Apple Java 6 End of Life
Apple has posted notice that Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) will be the last OS X release that supports Java 6, and as such, recommends developers whose applications depend on Java 6 to migrate their apps to a newer Java version provided by Oracle.
Apple Java 6 for Mac OS X
For Java versions 6 and below, Apple supplies their own version of Java...

In any case Java 6 end of life happened in 2018. It is an extremely old, unsupported and unsecure version of Java. The current minimum in the industry is JDK 8, but most projects are moving to JDK 17 or 21 out of necessity.
As mentioned in the comments you could try building JDK 6 from the source but it likely to find many issues as JDK 6 didn't support macOS as a target.
Source: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_6.html
